# Prove/Disprove for $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N,$ if $f\circ f$ is periodic then $f$ is periodic

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

We define periodic according to the standard definition where $f(x)=f(x+p)$, this means that there exists p so that $f(f(x)) = f(f(x)+p)$.

However I am unable to find a counter example or a constructing a formal proof. Any insights are welcome

Comment: Use mathjax please

Comment: It would seem to mean it would mean $f(f(x))=f(f(x+p)),$ not $f(f(x)+p).$

Comment: Define $f: \mathbb{N} \to  \mathbb{N}$ by $f(n)=2$ if $n$ is even and $f(n)=2n$ if $n$ is odd. Then $f\circ f$ is constant (hence periodic) but $f$ is not periodic.

Comment: An observation that could guide your search for a counterexample: consider what would be true if $f$ were injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start with

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \text {if $x$ is even}\\
1, & \text {if $x$ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

This has $f\circ f = f$ periodic. Now find a small change $f'$ to $f$ such that $f'\circ f' = f$ (so periodic), but $f'$ becomes "slightly " non-periodic.

Comment: Ok it seems I have over complicated things when solving